# Ionic 3: FileTransferError with Null Exception When downloading image from Firebase

Tags: cordova, ionic3, firebase-storage, file-transfer

**What i want to do:** I'm trying to download image from firebase. I have a Url and I want to save the image in local storage so when device is offline i can fetch the pics and show it.

**What i did so far:**
so I used FileTransfer plugin to download the images which sadly is not working.
Here is m code.

```
 var url ='https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aswj-companion-3c915.appspot.com/o/eventImages%2Fcyc-720x340.png?alt=media&token=7aa67766-f532-479f-bd53-30a0a57c8de6'
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
    fileTransfer.download(url ,this.storageDirectory+"image").then((entry) => {
        console.log(entry.toURL())
        const alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: 'Success',
          message: `Downlaoded Succefully ${entry.toURL()}`,
          buttons: ['OK']
        });

        alert.present();
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(error)
  }
```

It's giving me This error...

> FileTransferError { code: 1
>   source: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/aswj-companion-3c915.appspot.com/o/eventImages%2Fcyc-720x340.png?alt=media&token=7aa67766-f532-479f-bd53-30a0a57c8de6"
>   target: "filesystem:file:///persistent/file0"
>   http_status: null
>   body: null
>   exception: null

I know

> Code 1

means file not found but image is actually there. So i don't know what to do.I searched through other question similar to this but i can't seem to understand what's the problem.
 i think the problem is in Url. but how to make it work?

Comment: The ` target: "filesystem:file:///persistent/file0" ` is weird, especially since it doesn't contain "image". You might want to double check that, try to give it the right extension (.jpg or whatever) and make sure you have the authorisation to write there.

Comment: You are right i think. how can i forget. i'm so idiot. but still getting same error ! code 1 and body, exception null

Comment: @EricDarchis didn't work! i tried giving extension like .jpg but it still giving same error